Odom tf going perpendicular
I'm using a ros2 diff_drive_controller to pilot and generate odometry on a typical 2 wheels base.
Piloting the robot from the "cmd_vel" twist message is working well, I believe my urdf and joints configuration is fine but for some reason, the odom tf generated by the diff_drive_controller moves 90° from the direction of movement of the robot (thus the robot is sliding like it was on mecanum wheel). I can't figure out where could be the issue or where I could add a 90° transform.
SE won't let me upload the gif, so you can see the behaviour in this GIF
Here is my controller yaml.
diff_drive_base_controller:
 ros__parameters:
  left_wheel_names: ["left_wheel_joint"]
  right_wheel_names: ["right_wheel_joint"]

  wheel_separation: 0.36
  #wheels_per_side: 1  # actually 2, but both are controlled by 1 signal
  wheel_radius: 0.1

  wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.0
  left_wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0
  right_wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0

  publish_rate: 50.0
  odom_frame_id: odom
  base_frame_id: base_link
  pose_covariance_diagonal : [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.01]
  twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.01]

  open_loop: true
  enable_odom_tf: true

  cmd_vel_timeout: 0.5
  #publish_limited_velocity: true
  use_stamped_vel: false
  #velocity_rolling_window_size: 10

  # Velocity and acceleration limits
  # Whenever a min_* is unspecified, default to -max_*
  linear.x.has_velocity_limits: true
  linear.x.has_acceleration_limits: true
  linear.x.has_jerk_limits: false
  linear.x.max_velocity: 3.0
  linear.x.min_velocity: -3.0
  linear.x.max_acceleration: 2.0
  linear.x.max_jerk: 0.0
  linear.x.min_jerk: 0.0

  angular.z.has_velocity_limits: true
  angular.z.has_acceleration_limits: true
  angular.z.has_jerk_limits: false
  angular.z.max_velocity: 3.14
  angular.z.min_velocity: -3.14
  angular.z.max_acceleration: 3.0
  angular.z.min_acceleration: -3.0
  angular.z.max_jerk: 0.0
  angular.z.min_jerk: 0.0

and the xacro file of the robot.
And the full source code if you are interested.
Any idea where it could come from ?

Looks like that robot was defined in a strange way. I assume the 2 small balls I see in the front and back of the robot (where the depth (?) camera points is front) is the caster_f and caster_b. Looking at the joints, they are defined as ±0.3 in y. This means that the back and front of the robot appears to be defined in the y-axis...
If this is indeed the case, one way to workaround it is to add a -90 degree rotation to base_link, so the rest of the robot is properly rotated, or to the plugin, so to the plugin, its +x is +y of the robot, though I would suggest to not keep this technical debt and define the front and back in the x direction instead...

Awesome thanks ! Indeed, I just added a -1.5708 rad rotation around Z between the base_link (dummy link) and the chassis. That's good enough for now, I'm not sure if and why this could become a technical debt in the future.
Do you know of any convention that says the front of the robot should be on the X axis ?
I have to admit the angle I added the wheels is not very intuitive but I would expect from the diff_drive_controller to just take into account the axles of the wheel as Y direction for the odometry. For various reasons in a mechanism the axle could not be perfectly aligned with X.

As long as the URDF is set right, diff_drive_controller will publish the right transforms. I would like to add (and stress) that the workaround, in my opinion, feels like a technical debt in terms of ease-of-understanding and maintainability because when the next person wants to add something, linked to the chassis frame, they would have to be aware about adding something towards the "forwards" of the robot in the y direction instead of x. REP-103 recommends that the direction of x is forwards.

The diff-drive controller assumes that the positive x-axis of your base_link frame points "forward".
